# With JQuery check if an attribute exists before doing something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to modify the [grid.js thumbnail system](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/). I added 4 more links to the original version, so that I can add a Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and "Other" buttons to the "Website" which is already present in the tutorial:

```
 <li>
 <h4 class="date">4-10 Jan</h4>
 <img src="..." class="..." alt="..." />
 <h4>some text</h4>
 <a id="1" href="websiteurlhere" data-largesrc="imageurlhere" data-title="texthere" data-n2="facebookhere" data-n3="twitterhere" data-n4="linkedinhere" data-n5="ohterlinkhere"><img src="plussign.png" alt="img01"/></a> 
 </li>
```

And this is the changed code inside grid.js

```
Preview.prototype = {
    create : function() {
        // create Preview structure:
        this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
        this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
        this.$href = $( '<a href="#">Visit website</a>&nbsp;' );
        this.$spacer = ( '&nbsp;&nbsp;' );
        this.$face = $( '<a href="#">Facebook</a>');
        this.$twitter = $( '<a href="#">Twitter</a>');
        this.$linkedin = $( '<a href="#">LinkedIn</a>');
        this.$other = $( '<a href="#">Other Link</a>');
        this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href, this.$spacer, this.$face, this.$spacer, this.$twitter, this.$spacer, this.$linkedin, this.$spacer, this.$other );

        this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
        this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
        this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
        this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
        this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
        // append preview element to the item
        this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
        // set the transitions for the preview and the item
        if( support ) {
            this.setTransition();
        }
    },
    update : function( $item ) {

        if( $item ) {
            this.$item = $item;
        }

        // if already expanded remove class "og-expanded" from current item and add it to new item
        if( current !== -1 ) {
            var $currentItem = $items.eq( current );
            $currentItem.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
            this.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
            // position the preview correctly
            this.positionPreview();
        }

        // update current value
        current = this.$item.index();

        // update preview´s content
        var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
            eldata = {
                href : $itemEl.attr( 'href' ),
                largesrc : $itemEl.data( 'largesrc' ),
                title : $itemEl.data( 'title' ),
                face : $itemEl.data('n2'),
                twitter : $itemEl.data('n3'),
                linkedin : $itemEl.data('n4'),
                other : $itemEl.data('n5'),
                description : $itemEl.data( 'description' )
            };

        this.$title.html( eldata.title );
        this.$description.html( eldata.description );
        this.$href.attr( 'href', eldata.href );
            this.$face.attr( 'href', eldata.face );
            this.$twitter.attr( 'href', eldata.twitter );
            this.$linkedin.attr( 'href', eldata.linkedin );
            this.$other.attr( 'href', eldata.other );
```

Now. I create the list with PHP, so there may or may not be all the links inside every specific record. So, I want to check if inside the "a" the code is dealing with, "data-n2", "data-n3", "data-n4", "data-n5" actually exist. If they don't, don't append anything to the preview.

I thought of adding an if in the first part, inside the `create Preview strucure`. I tried every system I could find on stackoverflow. I tried:

- `if ($itemEl.data('n3') != "")`
- `if ($node->hasAttribute('data-n3'))`
- `if (this.hasAttribute("data-n3"))`
- `if ($element.is("[data-n3]"))`
- `if ($(element).attr('data-n3'))`
- `if (this.$item.children( 'a' ).data('3'))`

And probably others I can't even remember. Nothing works. It brakes the code (the result is that the "plus" icon point directly to the href instead of interpreting the grid preview code).

What can I do? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to check for the existence of the attributes and that there is a value within each of the data-n1 - data-n3 attributes?  I'd probably use the fact that an empty string, null and undefined would all be 'falsey' and do something like the below (the if statement is obviously the relevant bit).

This works fine for me:

```
var test = false;
if ($itemEl.data('n3')) test = true;
alert(test);
```

Comment: You understand correctly. Problem is that $itemEl is initiated after the bit I need to check for existance in. I need to check for the existance of those attributes before executing lines 8 to 11 (as showed in the code above). But even if I copy `var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
    eldata = {
     face : $itemEl.data('n2'),
     twitter : $itemEl.data('n3'),
     linkedin : $itemEl.data('n4'),
     other : $itemEl.data('n5'),
     description : $itemEl.data( 'description' )
    };` 
before line 8, it still does not work.

Comment: Hard to tell from the snippet, but it looks like this.$item might point to the same thing in create() that $itemEl points to in update().  As for conditionally adding them, it might be easiest to break up that append statement so you add them one at a time based on whether the attributes exist.  Otherwise, potentially create an array, and only conditionally add to that the JQuery objects you want appended based on existence or otherwise of attributes, and pass that as the param to append.

Comment: Yep, I need to break down the append. Infact, That's what I am trying right now, but I still miss the condition to check inside the IF.